# Strtotime won't convert my date accurately

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I know this is a common problem, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.  In my last question [complicated date functions - comparing, subtracting I needed to compare timestamps to get an accurate date for some Cisco logs.

The best I can come up with (since the dates don't actually feature the year) is in the format
     Mar  1 2013 00:03:55:
from
     Mar  1 00:03:55:

But when I ran some tests, strtotime is converting this date as 
     Jan 1970
Using
     print date("M Y", strtotime($c_log))."\n";

Am I going to have to reformat it into a date it can understand?  I don't appear to have the DateTime function.  What's the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
echo date('M Y', strtotime('Mar 1 00:03:55')); // outputs Mar 2013
```

it should default to the current year when one isn't included.

Comment: It's the final colon that does it.  Strange.  I'll have to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `date_parse_from_format()` function so you can specify the format
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php